# Can FirePHP be configured to tell where it's been called from when it logs?

Tags: php, firephp

I'm helping a colleague with a legacy, spaghetti code application. There are thousands of calls in it to `$firephp->log`, but we're trying to track down a particular one.

Can FirePHP be configured to include, with every log statement, the location it was called from in the code?

Answer (score 0):

FirePHP is itself written in PHP, therefore you can edit the `log` member function to add the tracing.  In original *FirePHP.class.php* file, function `log` looks like this:

```
public function log($Object, $Label=null) {
    return $this->fb($Object, $Label, FirePHP::LOG);
}
```

If you want to log the call, simply modify this method to be:

```
public function log($Object, $Label=null) {
    $this->trace($Label);
    return $this->fb($Object, $Label, FirePHP::LOG);
}
```

P.S. I have an older version of FirePHP on my system, so your code can be slightly different, but the changes would be about the same.